# Get Contact Emails of Currently Active Account as List

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, soql, salesforce-lightning

Given: A Salesforce user is viewing an account page.

Desired Output: All Emails of Contacts related to the Account currently viewed as a List object.

My code:

```
SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id'))
```

This does not retrieve any results. When using a fixed number instead of `ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id')`, the Emails are correctly returned.

I'm sort of new to Apex. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired output you need to use SOQL variable injection.

You can do this by creating a variable first and then referencing the variable inside the SOQL using `:` and the variable name:

```
String theAccountId = ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id');
List<Contact> theContacts = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = :theAccountId)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static query with a bind variable to retrieve the correct results.

Additionally, the [`Contact`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) object contains an `AccountId` field of its own. Therefore, depending on your setup, you may be able to eliminate your subquery. You may also want to filter out `Email` fields that are empty, since `Email` is not a required field.

The complete result could look something like this:

```
String accountId = ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('id');

List<Contact> accountContactsEmailList = [
  SELECT
    Email
  FROM
    Contact
  WHERE
    Email != ''
    AND AccountId = :accountId
];

for (Contact contact : accountContactsEmailList) {
  System.debug(contact.Email);
}
```